# Obtener un solo datos de dos consultas en Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, sql

Necesito realizar una consulta, en la cual si una subconsulta me devuelve un valor  `null` ejecute una segunda subconsulta la cual me garantiza devolver un valor las dos subconsultas devuelven el mismo valor.

```
FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
--------------------------
|Oct/2012 - Feb/2013     |
--------------------------
```

la primera consulta seria a si

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
          OVER (ORDER BY pac1.pac_final_date DESC)
  FROM    matricula mac
       INNER JOIN
          periodo pac1
       ON mac.pac_id = pac1.pac_id
 WHERE mac.ent_id = 26172 AND mac.mac_estado IN (8072, 10221)
```

y la segunda

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
             OVER (ORDER BY pac1.pac_final_date DESC)
     FROM  registro rea
          INNER JOIN
             periodo pac1
          ON rea.pac_id = pac1.pac_id
    WHERE rea.ent_id = 26172
```

Existen dos casos:

Caso -1 --> cuando ejecute la primera subconsulta me devuelve un valor y no sera necesario ejecutar la segunda subconsulta

Resultado

```
FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
--------------------------
|Oct/2012 - Feb/2013     |
--------------------------
```

Caso -2 --> cuando ejecuta la primera consulta y el valor de resultado sea `null` entonces deberá ejecutar la segunda subconsulta

Resultado

```
FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
--------------------------
|Oct/2012 - Feb/2013     |
--------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo sería utilizar la función `DECODE` de Oracle. La sintaxis de la función es :

```
DECODE(expr1,val1,ret1,val2,ret2,...,valn,retn,default)
```

Lo que hace la función es evaluar la expresión *expr1*. Si el valor concide con *val1*, devuelve *ret1*, si coincide con *val2* devuelve *ret2*, y así sucesivamente. Si el valor no corresponde con ninguno de los *valX*, devuelve un valor *default*.

En tu caso, la sentencia que buscas sería algo así :

```
SELECT decode(DISTINCT
   FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
      OVER (ORDER BY pac1.pac_final_date DESC),null,
         (SELECT DISTINCT
            FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
            OVER (ORDER BY pac1.pac_final_date DESC)
               FROM  registro rea
               INNER JOIN
               periodo pac1
               ON rea.pac_id = pac1.pac_id
            WHERE rea.ent_id = 26172)
   FROM    matricula mac
   INNER JOIN
      periodo pac1
   ON mac.pac_id = pac1.pac_id
   WHERE mac.ent_id = 26172 AND mac.mac_estado IN (8072, 10221)
```

Answer (score 0):

También podrías usar la clausula WITH y entonces te quedaría más o menos así:

```
WITH C1 AS 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name) 
          OVER (ORDER BY pac1.pac_final_date DESC) PACNAME
  FROM    matricula mac
       INNER JOIN
          periodo pac1
       ON mac.pac_id = pac1.pac_id
 WHERE mac.ent_id = 26172 AND mac.mac_estado IN (8072, 10221) 
),
C2 AS 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
          FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name) 
             OVER (ORDER BY pac1.pac_final_date DESC) PACNAME
     FROM  registro rea
          INNER JOIN
             periodo pac1
          ON rea.pac_id = pac1.pac_id
    WHERE rea.ent_id = 26172 
),
C3 AS 
(
SELECT (SELECT * FROM C1) C1PACNAME, (SELECT * FROM C2) C2PACNAME FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT NVL(C1PACNAME,C2PACNAME) PACNAME FROM C3 ;
```

esto no lo he podido probar bien porque no tengo tus tablas, pero puedes variar un poco según te convenga.